# Web Bluetooth: Can't pair BLE device with Mobile Device with Live Server VS Code extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, web-bluetooth, nrf52

I'm a beginner in the Web Development world. I want to pair a BLE device (NRF52840 DK) with my mobile device through a web page. I tested an example for Web Bluetooth and it works fine on my PC as you can see on the following image:

Pairing my PC (Chrome) with a BLE device successfully

[image]

I did it through the popular extension Live Server on VS Code. When I tried to access to that page on my mobile (Android) using my IP and port, and pressed the button nothing happened.

Pairing my mobile (Chrome) with a BLE device unsuccessfully

[image]

Is there something that I'm not taking into consideration?

Here is the HTML & JS code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BLE WebApp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <button>Connect with BLE device</button>
        </form>

        <script>
            var deviceName = 'Nordic_HRM'

            function isWebBluetoothEnabled() {
                if (!navigator.bluetooth) {
                    console.log('Web Bluetooth API is not available in this browser!')
                    return false
                }
                return true
            }

            function getDeviceInfo() {
                let chosenHeartRateService = null;
            
                console.log('Requesting Bluetooth Device...')
                navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ services: ['heart_rate'] }] })
                .then(device => device.gatt.connect())
                .then(server => {
                    console.log("Getting HR Service…")
                    return server.getPrimaryService('heart_rate');
                })
                .then(service => {
                    chosenHeartRateService = service;
                    return Promise.all([
                        service.getCharacteristic('heart_rate_measurement')
                        .then(handleHeartRateMeasurementCharacteristic),
                    ]);
                })
            }

            function handleHeartRateMeasurementCharacteristic(characteristic) {
            return characteristic.startNotifications()
            .then(char => {
                characteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged',
                                                onHeartRateChanged);
            });
            }

            function onHeartRateChanged(event) {
                const characteristic = event.target;
                console.log(parseHeartRate(characteristic.value));
            }

            function parseHeartRate(data) {
                const flags = data.getUint8(0);
                const rate16Bits = flags & 0x1;
                const result = {};
                let index = 1;
                if (rate16Bits) {
                    result.heartRate = data.getUint16(index, /*littleEndian=*/true);
                    index += 2;
                } else {
                    result.heartRate = data.getUint8(index);
                    index += 1;
                }
                const contactDetected = flags & 0x2;
                const contactSensorPresent = flags & 0x4;
                if (contactSensorPresent) {
                    result.contactDetected = !!contactDetected;
                }
                const energyPresent = flags & 0x8;
                if (energyPresent) {
                    result.energyExpended = data.getUint16(index, /*littleEndian=*/true);
                    index += 2;
                }
                const rrIntervalPresent = flags & 0x10;
                if (rrIntervalPresent) {
                    const rrIntervals = [];
                    for (; index + 1 < data.byteLength; index += 2) {
                    rrIntervals.push(data.getUint16(index, /*littleEndian=*/true));
                    }
                    result.rrIntervals = rrIntervals;
                }
                return result;
            }

            document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation()
                event.preventDefault()
            
                if (isWebBluetoothEnabled()) {
                    getDeviceInfo()
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should add the picture to be visible instead of a link to it.

Comment: It's my first question, and I don't have enough reputation to post full pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in the way you describe it.
Web Bluetooth only works on pages which has HTTPS enabled. It works on localhost too for testing purposes. Since you access the web application via an IP-address which doesn't have HTTPS enabled, Web Bluetooth is not available.

https://web.dev/bluetooth/#https-only

You can test this by adding a text to the page with a boolean or other text which will show if web bluetooth is available.

```
function isWebBluetoothEnabled() {
    if (!navigator.bluetooth) {
        console.log('Web Bluetooth API is not available in this browser!')
        document.getElementById('bluetoothState').innerText = 'Not available'
        return false
    }
    document.getElementById('bluetoothState').innerText = 'Available'
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mkcert` to create a certificate
usage:

```sh
mkcert 127.0.0.1 localhost 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.X
```

use the files generated to add it to settings.json file in .vscode directory (create if doesn't exist)

```json
{
    "liveServer.settings.https": {
        "enable": true,
        "cert": "/full/path/to/file/192.168.0.108+3.pem",
        "key": "/full/path/to/file/192.168.0.108+3-key.pem",
        "passphrase": ""
    }
}
```

this will create a warning once due to the nature of self signed certificates, but it'll make sure almost all features of https work.
The issue I faced using this method is that it is considered not secure enough to install a PWA on a local device by chrome.